# Two table compare and list php

Tags: php, mysql

there are two different tables. I want to find the expressions with "%USD" in the columns of the same name in these two tables do not match and list them on the screen.

Table 1 query;

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$queb = $conn->query("select distinct symbol from tableA WHERE symbol LIKE '%USD'"); 
while ($resb = $queb->fetch_assoc()){
$symbolb = $resb['symbol'];
}

?>
```

table 2 query;

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$quec = $conn->query("select distinct symbol from tableB WHERE symbol LIKE '%USD'"); 
while ($resc = $quec->fetch_assoc()){
$symbolc = $resc['symbol'];

}
?>
```

How can I list expressions that are not between two tables?

Comment: it sounds like full outer join

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not be understanding your question fully. If you want to list symbols that begin with 'USD' that are in `tableA` but not in `tableB` along with symbols in `tableB` that begin with `USD` that are not in `tableA`, then the following query should return those symbols:

```
select distinct symbol from tableA
    where symbol LIKE '%USD' and symbol not in (select distinct symbol from tableB)
union
select distinct symbol from tableB
    where symbol LIKE '%USD' and symbol not in (select distinct symbol from tableA)
```

Or you can use outer joins instead:

```
select distinct symbol from tableA left join tableB on tableA.symbol = tableB.symbol
    where tableA.symbol like ('%USD') and tableB.symbol is null
union
select distinct symbol from tableB left join tableA on tableB.symbol = tableA.symbol
    where tableB.symbol like ('%USD') and tableA.symbol is null
```

In either case, performance will be improved in you have indexes on the `symbol` columns.

Comment: working great! thanks thanks @booboo